# How to remove the empty line that VBA creates when saving to CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-to-csv

How do I remove the last empty line that the VBA creates when you save a sheet to a csv?

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()
Dim strSourceSheet As String
Dim strFullname As String


strSourceSheet = "Sheet1"
strFullname = "\\H:\filepath\filepath1\"
myfilenamedate = Format(Range("C2"), "yyyyMMdd")
myfilenameindicator = "data"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname & myfilenameindicator & myfilenamedate & ".csv", _
                      FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                      CreateBackup:=True, _
                      local:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close


End Sub
```

I have updated the code to @FaneDuru's specification and when this code is expressed in this manner it still returns an error. If someone can assist it helping understand what is happening it would be much appreciated. My VBA understanding is quite limited.

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()
Function eliminateEmptyRow(fullName As String) As Boolean
 'Necessary a reference to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0"
 Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, txtStr As TextStream, objOutputFile As TextStream, strText As String
 
  If Dir(fullName) <> "" Then 'check if file exists
    Set txtStr = fso.OpenTextFile(fullName)
        strText = txtStr.ReadAll
    txtStr.Close
  Else
    eliminateEmptyRow = False: Exit Function
  End If
  strText = left(strText, Len(strText) - 2)

   Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fullName)
      objOutputFile.Write strText
   objOutputFile.Close
   eliminateEmptyRow = True
End Function

Dim strSourceSheet As String
Dim strFullname As String


strSourceSheet = "Sheet1"
strFullname = "\\H:\filepath\filepath1\"
myfilenamedate = Format(Range("C2"), "yyyyMMdd")
myfilenameindicator = "data"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname & myfilenameindicator & myfilenamedate & ".csv", _
                      FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                      CreateBackup:=True, _
                      local:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

If Not eliminateEmptyRow(strFullname & myfilenameindicator & myfilenamedate & ".csv") Then Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think it is adding an extra line?  When I save a CSV file from Excel, the data stored runs from the first row with data on the sheet to the last row with data on the sheet.  The last line in the CSV file itself ends with `EOL`.

Comment: The *line delimiter* for the CSV is \r\n so it will naturally end with one.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am opening the file in notepad and I can see that there is a space at the end.

Comment: Notepad is inviting you to add data after the last {CrLf}. That doesn't mean there's something there. There isn't. There is no way to suppress the last {CrLf} when it's created using built in save-as-CSV functionality. You could write your own CSV file exporter (more hassle than it's worth, trust me - unless the file is very simple). You could manipulate the file after saving, as per @FaneDuru's response - or you could investigate why the final {CrLf} is causing an issue downstream and resolve it there.

Comment: Are you seeing an actual space?  Or are you seeing the cursor at the beginning of the next line (which would be expected)?  If you are seeing an actual space, then examine your worksheet for the presence of a space after what you think is your data.  When I examine a CSV file saved from Excel with a Hex Editor, there are no trailing spaces or extra lines.

Comment: Aside from seeing something in Notepad, what problem are you running into because of this?

Comment: It’s is data that needs to follow a specific data structure and the empty cell, \r\n, creates an error once uploaded to the database.

Comment: But if it’s due to functionality then I need employ @FaneDuru method. Will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try please the next approach. Naturally Excel inserts an empty line to append if you need that. The next function should open the created file and should eliminate the `VbCrLf` from the end:

```
Function eliminateEmptyRow(fullName As String) As Boolean
 'Necessary a reference to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0"
 Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, txtStr As TextStream, objOutputFile As TextStream, strText As String
 
  If Dir(fullName) <> "" Then 'check if file exists
    Set txtStr = fso.OpenTextFile(fullName)
        strText = txtStr.ReadAll
    txtStr.Close
  Else
    eliminateEmptyRow = False: Exit Function
  End If
  strText = left(strText, Len(strText) - 2)

   Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fullName)
      objOutputFile.Write strText
   objOutputFile.Close
   eliminateEmptyRow = True
End Function
```

Insert the next line after `ActiveWorkbook.Close`:

```
If Not eliminateEmptyRow(strFullname & myfilenameindicator & myfilenamedate & ".csv") Then Stop
```

Test it, please and send some feedback.

***Edited***, to include the function call in the original code:

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()
  Dim strSourceSheet As String
  Dim strFullname As String

  strSourceSheet = "Sheet1"
  strFullname = "\\H:\filepath\filepath1\"
  myfilenamedate = Format(Range("C2"), "yyyyMMdd")
  myfilenameindicator = "data"

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname & myfilenameindicator & 
  myfilenamedate & ".csv", _
                      FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                      CreateBackup:=True, _
                      local:=True
  ActiveWorkbook.Close

  If Not eliminateEmptyRow(strFullname & myfilenameindicator & myfilenamedate & ".csv") Then Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: Did you find some time to test the above suggestion? Didn't it work as you need?

Comment: To be honest @FaneDuru, I am not very good at VBA. I am struggling to implement it into my existing code. Can you please assist?

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: But the above solution gives you everything you need, I think. In the code in your question, you simple insert the recommended line `If Not eliminateEmptyRow(strFullname & myfilenameindicator & myfilenamedate & ".csv") Then Stop`.  After `ActiveWorkbook.Close` and run the code. The code will stop on this line if something wrong will appear. Normally everything will work smooth.

Comment: it results in a Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: Didn't you copy the `eliminateEmptyRow` function? If yes, did you set a reference to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0"? If not, do you know how to do that? It is simple, in fact...

Comment: I've added you code to the question and it still seems to give me a problem. Maybe if you can update your code, to include your elements, it will assist me in understanding how my VBA coding is incorrect.

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: OK. I updated the above code to include the function call. But you did not answer none of my above questions... **Did you set a reference to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0"**?   If not, **do you know how to do that**? I suppose that **you copied the function code**... Am I right?

Comment: In response to your Microsoft Script Control 1.0, I do not know how to to change my settings to that reference. I read up on it and watched a few videos. It's my first VBA function ever.

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: This is not a problem. A problem is that **you do not answer my questions** and I cannot help if I do not know what you did or you did not... So, in order to set the reference you must go in VBE (Visual Basic for Application Editor - the window where you are when copy the above code), then Tools (menu) -> References..., scroll down until you see the above recommended reference, check it and press OK. At least, did you copy the above function in your module?

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I will try my best to be clearer moving forward. Ja, I copied it through now and added an "_" at the end of line 11. I also checked the "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" and I still get a, "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined" so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: I do  not know which the line 11 is and why was it necessary. If you added after `local:=True` this is wrong. Then, when you speak about an error you should meantion/copy the code line where the error appear... So, on which line does it show up? I mean the yellow one...

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: I will leave my office in some minutes. If you are not enough responsive, I do not know how we can solve your problem... At least, are you referring to your adapted code or to mine, when you mention line 11?

Comment: I am talking about your code. So edit please be aware. Line 11 is [ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname & myfilenameindicator &] but I added a [_] to the end of the sentence and it fixed the problem of the line being incomplete i.e. syntax error. The current error is [Sub SaveAsCSV()]

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: I only copied your code. Somehow that line has been lost. But did you copy my adapted code and you still have yours? If yes, VBA cannot admit two Subs with the same name... But the error should be concludent form this point of view. Is this the case? What message does the error show?

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: Now I will leave my office. I will look to your comments when I will be at home. But, please, try be more focused on the way you explain what happens. Saying that an error appear does not help at all. You must say what exactly the error message is and on which line it appears.

Comment: thank you for your extensive help on the matter. I think I'm going to rest on it till I get better at VBA coding. Hopefully, you will be on the assisting side again.

Comment: @Cheryl Emvula: Did you find a way to make it working?

Comment: I have not. I think its something I am doing wrong but will keep playing around till I come right.